# Firebase upload image with dialog but dialog not call dismiss is still working in onSuccess

Tags: java, android

I want after finish upload to dismiss my dialog but it still working what the problem? how can I solve the proplem on my code ??? What is still my code dialog work not hidden  I search  but I don't have answer

```
        while (up < mArrayUri.size()) {

                    filepath.child(mArrayUri.get(k).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mArrayUri.get(k))
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



                               String downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString();
                                    String imgGet = "img" + c;
                                    if (imgGet.equalsIgnoreCase("img1")) {
                                        value.put("img1", downloadURL);

                                    }


                                    if (imgGet.equalsIgnoreCase("img2")) {
                                        value.put("img2", downloadURL);

                                    }

                                    if (imgGet.equalsIgnoreCase("img3")) {
                                        value.put("img3", downloadURL);

                                    }


                                    c++;


                                    referenceAddReport.setValue(value);


                   dialog.dismiss();

                                }

                            });
                    up++;
                    k++;


                }
```

Comment: Is your code accessing to the line `dialog.dismiss()`? I mean is your code entering in the onSuccess? can you put more code please? At least the dialog initialization and everything, thanks

Answer (score 0):

filepath.child(mArrayUri.get(k).getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mArrayUri.get(k))
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

```
                            dialog.dismiss();

                           String downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString();
                                String imgGet = "img" + c;
                                if (imgGet.equalsIgnoreCase("img1")) {
                                    value.put("img1", downloadURL);

                                }


                                if (imgGet.equalsIgnoreCase("img2")) {
                                    value.put("img2", downloadURL);

                                }

                                if (imgGet.equalsIgnoreCase("img3")) {
                                    value.put("img3", downloadURL);

                                }


                                c++;


                                referenceAddReport.setValue(value);
```

finish();

```
                            }

                        });
```